# How to bind a store variable in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I am trying to bind a variable from my store to a component, but get the error:

```
[!] (plugin svelte) ValidationError: Cannot bind to a variable which is not writable
```

Here is my sample code:

```
<Textfield bind:value={startDate} label="Start Date" type="datetime-local" />
```

Answer (score 6):

To use a store variable, one can rely on the "update" callback, or use the specific syntax

```
<Textfield bind:value={$startDate} label="Start Date" type="datetime-local" />
```

More information on the Svelte tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/store-bindings